# Looking for an efficient implementation of the reverse of lzip or interleave in Tcl: Building sublists with every nth item

Tags: list, tcl

[This](http://wiki.tcl.tk/12187) describes an `interleave` function that can `lzip` data:

```
% interleave {a b c} {1 2 3}
a 1 b 2 c 3
```

I am looking for the reverse operation. Also I would like to specify into how many sublists the input shall be split. For example:

```
% lnth {a 1 b 2 c 3}  1
{a 1 b 2 c 3}

% lnth {a 1 b 2 c 3}  2
{a b c} {1 2 3}

% lnth {a 1 b 2 c 3}  3
{a 2} {1 c} {b 3}

% lnth {a 1 b 2 c 3}  6
{a} {1} {b} {2} {c} {3}
```

For uneven splits, the missing elements shall be just omitted. If you feel like it you could provide a default argument to be filled in, but that's not required. Also I don't mind the exact quotation of the two corner cases where `n==1` or `n==[llength $L]`. Thanks Hai Vu for pointing this out in your earlier answer.

It would be good to have some notion of complexity in time and memory.

I'm on Tcl8.4 (this cannot be changed).

**Update**

For these kind of benchmark question its always good to have a central summary. All tests ran on the same machine, on the (rather small) example list `$L` as shown below. It's all highly un-scientific.Good code comes from the answers below, errors are mine.

Test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh


proc build_list {len} {
    incr len
    while {[incr len -1]} {
        lappend res {}
    }
    set res
}



proc lnth3_prebuild_no_modulo {L n} {
    # Build empty 2D list to hold result
    set iterations [expr {int(ceil(double([llength $L]) / $n))}]
    set one [build_list $iterations]
    set res [list]
    set cnt [expr {$n+1}]
    while {[incr cnt -1]} {
        lappend res $one
    }

    # Fill in original/real values
    set iteration 0
    set subListNumber 0
    foreach item $L {
        lset res $subListNumber $iteration $item
        if {[incr subListNumber] == $n} {
            set subListNumber 0
            incr iteration
        }
    }
    set res
}


proc lnth3_no_modulo {L n} {
    # Create a list of variables: subList0, subList1, subList2, ...
    for {set subListNumber 0} {$subListNumber < $n} {incr subListNumber} {
        set subList$subListNumber {}
    }

    # Build the sub-lists    
    set subListNumber 0
    foreach item $L {
        lappend subList$subListNumber $item
        if {[incr subListNumber] == $n} {
            set subListNumber 0
        }
    }

    # Build the result from all the sub-lists    
    set result {}
    for {set subListNumber 0} {$subListNumber < $n} {incr subListNumber} {
        lappend result [set subList$subListNumber]
    }

    return $result
}


proc lnth {L n} {
    set listvars ""
    for {set cnt 0} {$cnt < $n} {incr cnt} {
        lappend listvars "L$cnt"
    }

    set iterations [expr {ceil(double([llength $L]) / $n)}]
    for {set cnt 0} {$cnt < $iterations} {incr cnt} {
        foreach listvar $listvars el [lrange $L [expr {$cnt*$n}] [expr {($cnt+1)*$n-1}] ] {
            lappend $listvar $el
        }
    }

    set res [list]
    foreach listvar $listvars {
        lappend res [eval "join \$$listvar"]
    }
    set res
}


proc lnth_prebuild {L n} {
    set iterations [expr {int(ceil(double([llength $L]) / $n))}]
    set one [build_list $iterations]

    set listvars ""
    for {set cnt 0} {$cnt < $n} {incr cnt} {
        lappend listvars L$cnt
        set L$cnt $one
    }

    for {set cnt 0} {$cnt < $iterations} {incr cnt} {
        foreach listvar $listvars el [lrange $L [expr {$cnt*$n}] [expr {($cnt+1)*$n-1}] ] {
            lset $listvar $cnt $el
        }
    }

    set res [list]
    foreach listvar $listvars {
        lappend res [eval "join \$$listvar"]
    }
    set res
}



proc lnth2 {L n} {
    set listLen [llength $L]
    set subListLen [expr {$listLen / $n}]
    if {$listLen % $n != 0} { incr subListLen }
    set result {}

    for {set iteration 0} {$iteration < $n} {incr iteration} {
        set subList {}
        for {set i $iteration} {$i < $listLen} {incr i $n} {
            lappend subList [lindex $L $i]
        }
        lappend result $subList
    }
    return $result
}


proc lnth3 {L n} {
    # Create a list of variables: subList0, subList1, subList2, ...
    for {set subListNumber 0} {$subListNumber < $n} {incr subListNumber} {
        set subList$subListNumber {}
    }

    # Build the sub-lists    
    set i 0
    foreach item $L {
        set subListNumber [expr {$i % $n}]
        lappend subList$subListNumber $item
        incr i
    }

    # Build the result from all the sub-lists    
    set result {}
    for {set subListNumber 0} {$subListNumber < $n} {incr subListNumber} {
        lappend result [set subList$subListNumber]
    }

    return $result
}



# stuff subcommands in a namespace
namespace eval ::unlzip {}

proc unlzip {L n} {
   # check if we have the proc already
   set name [format "::unlzip::arity%dunlzip" $n]
   if {[llength [info commands $name]]} {
      return [$name $L]
   } else {
      # create it
      proc $name {V} [::unlzip::createBody $n]
      return [$name $L]
   }
}

proc ::unlzip::createBody {n} {
   for {set i 0} {$i < $n} {incr i} {
       lappend names v$i
       lappend lnames lv$i
   }
   set lbody ""
   set ret {
   return [list }
   foreach lname $lnames name $names {
       append lbody [format {
       lappend %s $%s} $lname $name]
       append ret "\$$lname "
   }
   append ret {]}
   return [format {foreach {%s} $V { %s }
                   %s} $names $lbody $ret]
}




### Tests
set proc_reference lnth
set procs {lnth_prebuild lnth2 lnth3 unlzip lnth3_no_modulo lnth3_prebuild_no_modulo}
set L {a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4 e 5 f 6 g 7 h 8 j 9 i 10 k 11 l 12 m 13 n 14 o 15 p 16 q 17 r 18 s 19 t 20 u 21 v 22 w 23 x 24 y 25 z 26}
set Ns {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 13 26}

# Functional verification
foreach n $Ns {
    set expected [$proc_reference $L $n]
    foreach p $procs {
        set result [$p $L $n]
        if {$expected ne $result} {
            puts "Wrong result for proc $p, N=$n."
            puts "  Expected: $expected"
            puts "       Got: $result"
        }
    }
}

# Table header
puts -nonewline [format "%30s" {proc_name\N}]
foreach n $Ns {
    puts -nonewline [format "  %7d" $n]
}
puts ""

# Run benchmarks
foreach proc_name [concat $proc_reference $procs] {
    puts -nonewline [format "%30s" $proc_name]
    foreach n $Ns {
        puts -nonewline [format "  %7.2f" [lindex [time "$proc_name \$L $n" 10000] 0]]
    }
    puts ""
}
```

The results:

```
               proc_name\N        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10       13       26
                      lnth    33.34    23.73    21.88    20.51    21.33    21.33    22.41    23.07    23.36    25.59    26.09    38.39
             lnth_prebuild    41.14    31.00    28.88    27.24    28.48    29.06    30.45    31.46    31.43    34.65    34.45    49.10
                     lnth2     8.56     8.08     8.35     8.78     9.12     9.29     9.66     9.98    10.29    10.61    11.22    14.94
                     lnth3    17.15    18.35    18.91    19.55    20.55    21.42    22.24    23.54    23.71    24.27    25.79    33.78
                    unlzip     5.36     5.25     5.03     4.97     5.27     5.42     5.52     5.43     5.42     5.96     5.51     6.83
           lnth3_no_modulo    14.88    16.56    17.20    17.97    18.63    19.42    19.78    20.74    21.53    21.84    23.60    31.29
  lnth3_prebuild_no_modulo    14.44    13.30    12.83    12.51    12.51    12.43    12.36    12.41    12.41    12.83    12.70    14.09
```

Comment: The usual Tcl 8.4 comment applies: Tcl 8.4 reached End-Of-Life supportwise with the 8.4.20 release, after 11 years. So at least consider updating...

Comment: @schlenk: I do not think this comment is helpful, considering I made that a point in my question. Some people have to work with 3rd party tools which just have that interpreter built in. And sometimes those things are not changed for various reasons - compatibility being one of them.

Comment: @schlenk: By coincidence I just stumbled upon [this benchmark](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1611) of Tcl versions. While I often missed features of Tcl8.5, the work I've got to do often is performance sensitive and deals with big lists. After seeing that page, it's the first time I'm actually happy being stuck on 8.4.

Comment: @PherricOxide: I'd like to keep the Tcl8.4 tag because I believe that the syntax of 8.5 would allow some more answers which would not apply to this question. I'd rather someone ask the same question explicitly for 8.5. The `*` syntax might warrant that. Also, the performance of 8.5 and 8.4 behaves differently (although I haven't tested that for these particular answers)

Comment: @cfi, if you'd like to keep the tag, perhaps you should find other questions to which it could apply and propose an appropriate tag wiki.

Comment: @Charles: Why do you say that? Tcl like all programming languages has different syntax for different versions. Even if this is the first Q using that tag, and even if it remains the only one, the tag has significance to distinguish from Tcl8.5 and 8.6 versions. Hence the 8.4 tag has value even for 8.5 and 8.6 users. What's the downside of having this tag in general and particularly here on this Q?

Comment: @Johannes, PherricOxide, Charles: Would appreciate explanations/comments regarding the Tcl8.4 version tag on [this meta Q](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196318/introducing-tcl-version-tags-actively-prevented-with-q-rollbacks)

Comment: @cfi, what I mean is that tags with wikis that have been added to more than one question are less likely to be removed by those of us that don't favor new tags.  See you on Meta.

Comment: @Charles, yup. Only in this case Johannes feels very strongly about it and started to remove tags while I was tagging other questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be creating specialized procs on the fly:

Not sure how fast it is for larger N or larger sets, but should be quite fast for repeated runs, as you have nearly no overhead than straight calls to `foreach` and `lappend`.

```
package require Tcl 8.4

# stuff subcommands in a namespace
namespace eval ::unlzip {}

proc unlzip {L n} {
   # check if we have the proc already
   set name [format "::unlzip::arity%dunlzip" $n]
   if {[llength [info commands $name]]} {
      return [$name $L]
   } else {
      # create it
      proc $name {V} [::unlzip::createBody $n]
      return [$name $L]
   }
}

proc ::unlzip::createBody {n} {
   for {set i 0} {$i < $n} {incr i} {
       lappend names v$i
       lappend lnames lv$i
   }
   set lbody ""
   set ret {
   return [list }
   foreach lname $lnames name $names {
       append lbody [format {
       lappend %s $%s} $lname $name]
       append ret "\$$lname "
   }
   append ret {]}
   return [format {foreach {%s} $V { %s }
                   %s} $names $lbody $ret]
}

proc ::unlzip::arity1unlzip {V} {
   return [list $V]
}

# example how the function looks for N=2

proc ::unlzip::arity2unlzip {V} {
   foreach {v1 v2} $V {
      lappend lv1 $v1
      lappend lv2 $v2
   }
   return [list $lv1 $lv2]
}
```

The disassambled bytecode for Tcl 8.6 for the N=3 proc would look like this (via Tcl 8.6. `::tcl::unsupported::disassemble proc`:

```
ByteCode 0x00667988, refCt 1, epoch 5, interp 0x005E0B70 (epoch 5)
Source "foreach {v0 v1 v2} $V { \n\t      lappend lv0 $v0\n\t      "
Cmds 6, src 149, inst 86, litObjs 1, aux 1, stkDepth 3, code/src 0.00
Proc 0x00694368, refCt 1, args 1, compiled locals 9
  slot 0, scalar, arg, "V"
  slot 1, scalar, temp
  slot 2, scalar, temp
  slot 3, scalar, "v0"
  slot 4, scalar, "v1"
  slot 5, scalar, "v2"
  slot 6, scalar, "lv0"
  slot 7, scalar, "lv1"
  slot 8, scalar, "lv2"
Exception ranges 1, depth 1:
  0: level 0, loop, pc 17-57, continue 10, break 61
Commands 6:
  1: pc 0-63, src 0-94        2: pc 17-30, src 32-46
  3: pc 31-44, src 55-69        4: pc 45-57, src 78-93
  5: pc 64-84, src 120-148        6: pc 73-83, src 128-147
Command 1: "foreach {v0 v1 v2} $V { \n\t      lappend lv0 $v0\n\t      "
  (0) loadScalar1 %v0         # var "V"
  (2) storeScalar1 %v1        # temp var 1
  (4) pop
  (5) foreach_start4 0
            [data=[%v1], loop=%v2
             it%v1  [%v3, %v4, %v5]]
  (10) foreach_step4 0
            [data=[%v1], loop=%v2
             it%v1  [%v3, %v4, %v5]]
  (15) jumpFalse1 +46         # pc 61
Command 2: "lappend lv0 $v0"
  (17) startCommand +13 1     # next cmd at pc 30
  (26) loadScalar1 %v3        # var "v0"
  (28) lappendScalar1 %v6     # var "lv0"
  (30) pop
Command 3: "lappend lv1 $v1"
  (31) startCommand +13 1     # next cmd at pc 44
  (40) loadScalar1 %v4        # var "v1"
  (42) lappendScalar1 %v7     # var "lv1"
  (44) pop
Command 4: "lappend lv2 $v2 "
  (45) startCommand +13 1     # next cmd at pc 58
  (54) loadScalar1 %v5        # var "v2"
  (56) lappendScalar1 %v8     # var "lv2"
  (58) pop
  (59) jump1 -49      # pc 10
  (61) push1 0        # ""
  (63) pop
Command 5: "return [list $lv0 $lv1 $lv2 ]"
  (64) startCommand +21 2     # next cmd at pc 85, 2 cmds start here
Command 6: "list $lv0 $lv1 $lv2 "
  (73) loadScalar1 %v6        # var "lv0"
  (75) loadScalar1 %v7        # var "lv1"
  (77) loadScalar1 %v8        # var "lv2"
  (79) list 3
  (84) done
  (85) done
```

As straight forward as it gets..., well, if the lists are incomplete (`llength $L` modulo `$n` isn't zero) you would need some little extra checks. As long as the lists are balanced, you could als pre populate the lists and use `lset` instead of `lappend`, which is faster, as it doesn't reallocate the list array so often.

Comment: Excellent idea to take the dynamic code generation one level up!

Comment: There's a nice demo/explanation of dynamic code generation/code templating/currying, again [in the Tcl'ers Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1173)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach: build one sub-list at a time, then append to the result before building the next one.

```
proc lnth2 {L n} {
    set listLen [llength $L]
    set subListLen [expr {$listLen / $n}]
    if {$listLen % $n != 0} { incr subListLen }
    set result {}

    for {set iteration 0} {$iteration < $n} {incr iteration} {
        set subList {}
        for {set i $iteration} {$i < $listLen} {incr i $n} {
            lappend subList [lindex $L $i]
        }
        lappend result $subList
    }
    return $result
}
```

Let say that L = `{a 1 b 2 c 3}` and n = 2, then I will build the first sub-list `{a b c}` by picking out the 0th, 2nd, and 4th items from the original list, append that to the result and move on the the second sub-list. Likewise, the second sub-list will be the 1th, 3rd, and 5th items.

## Update

After reviewing my solution, I still don't like the fact that I have to use `lindex`. I imagine `lindex` has to travese the list in order to find the list item, and my solution placed `lindex` right inside a loop; which means we traverse the same list several times. The next attempt is to traverse the list only once. This time, I mimic your algorithm, but avoid using the list functions such as `lrange`.

```
proc lnth3 {L n} {
    # Create a list of variables: subList0, subList1, subList2, ...
    for {set subListNumber 0} {$subListNumber < $n} {incr subListNumber} {
        set subList$subListNumber {}
    }

    # Build the sub-lists    
    set i 0
    foreach item $L {
        set subListNumber [expr {$i % $n}]
        lappend subList$subListNumber $item
        incr i
    }

    # Build the result from all the sub-lists    
    set result {}
    for {set subListNumber 0} {$subListNumber < $n} {incr subListNumber} {
        lappend result [set subList$subListNumber]
    }

    return $result
}
```

Sadly, this attempt performs worse than my first attempt. I still don't understand why.

Comment: That is about 3x faster than my solution: `set L {a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4 e 5 f 6 g 7 h 8 j 9 i 10 k 11 l 12 m 13 n 14 o 15 p 16 q 17 r 18 s 19 t 20 u 21 v 22 w 23 x 24 y 25 z 26}` then `time {lnth $L 2} 1000` is 34us and for your `lnth2` it is 8.4us.

Comment: Also you deal more nicely with incomplete lists: My solution has an empty space between the last element of incomplete sublists and the closing brace `}` - it's functionally equivalent, but ugly nevertheless. Nice :-)

Comment: Kudos for sharing "Bad attempts"! I admit I was hoping for some O(N) magic like in some of the Tcl Wiki's list handling routines. `lset` performs decently, but I don't think building an empty list of lists upfront to then `lset` elements would be a better performer...

Comment: You are aware that `lindex` is _very_ fast; it has O(1) complexity. Tcl's lists are implemented with C arrays.

Comment: It is probably slower due to constructing the variable name for the variable in `lappend` dynamically, thats a bad operation (shimmer from int > string, than from string -> varname. If you need that, use an array to store the variables, after all, a Tcl array is just a collection of variables indexed by name.

Answer (score 1):

Got something now - but do not like it because it does not seem to be efficient:

```
proc lnth {L n} {
    set listvars ""
    for {set cnt 0} {$cnt < $n} {incr cnt} {
        lappend listvars "L$cnt"
    }

    set iterations [expr {ceil(double([llength $L]) / $n)}]
    for {set cnt 0} {$cnt < $iterations} {incr cnt} {
        foreach listvar $listvars el [lrange $L [expr {$cnt*$n}] [expr {($cnt+1)*$n-1}] ] {
            lappend $listvar $el
        }
    }

    set res [list]
    foreach listvar $listvars {
        lappend res [eval "join \$$listvar"]
    }
    set res
}
```

The trick is to have a couple of sublists, stored in variables `L0`, `L1`, `L2`, and to create those sublists dynamically, depending on how many (`$n`) are wanted.

The number of iterations then depends on `len($L)/$n`, using the `ceil()` here to cover incomplete iterations.

The last loop assembles the overall result list.

I simply do not know how to get around constructing the result list more efficiently during the main work loop. And I know too little about the internal efficiencies of Tcl in `lappend` or alternatives. Also it may be faster to just iterate over L and dole out elements to those sublists...

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, and inspired by Donal's comment that `linsert` is actually `O(1)` because Tcl lists are implemented with C arrays, I tried to improve [Hai Vu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17887921/923794) a little: First be removing the modulo operation with a simple counter and comparison. And second by replacing the `lappend` with an `lset`. This latter change requires to prebuild the result array.

Here's the code:

```
proc lnth3_no_modulo {L n} {
    # Create a list of variables: subList0, subList1, subList2, ...
    for {set subListNumber 0} {$subListNumber < $n} {incr subListNumber} {
        set subList$subListNumber {}
    }

    # Build the sub-lists    
    set subListNumber 0
    foreach item $L {
        lappend subList$subListNumber $item
        if {[incr subListNumber] == $n} {
            set subListNumber 0
        }
    }

    # Build the result from all the sub-lists    
    set result {}
    for {set subListNumber 0} {$subListNumber < $n} {incr subListNumber} {
        lappend result [set subList$subListNumber]
    }

    return $result
}




proc build_list {len} {
    incr len
    while {[incr len -1]} {
        lappend res {}
    }
    set res
}
proc lnth3_prebuild_no_modulo {L n} {
    # Build empty 2D list to hold result
    set iterations [expr {int(ceil(double([llength $L]) / $n))}]
    set one [build_list $iterations]
    set res [list]
    set cnt [expr {$n+1}]
    while {[incr cnt -1]} {
        lappend res $one
    }

    # Fill in original/real values
    set iteration 0
    set subListNumber 0
    foreach item $L {
        lset res $subListNumber $iteration $item
        if {[incr subListNumber] == $n} {
            set subListNumber 0
            incr iteration
        }
    }
    set res
}
```

These two make small improvements on the run time - but not by much:

```
               proc_name\N        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10       13       26
                     lnth3    17.41    18.62    19.07    19.99    21.39    21.45    23.90    23.58    23.62    24.50    25.67    33.91
           lnth3_no_modulo    14.95    16.39    16.95    17.80    18.20    19.17    19.86    20.62    21.23    21.99    23.40    31.71
  lnth3_prebuild_no_modulo    14.46    12.90    12.24    11.85    11.80    11.65    11.61    11.61    11.70    11.81    11.96    13.23
```

It seems the prebuild alternative becomes more effective the more `lappend` list operations would have to be done otherwise.

Comment: `lset` requires Tcl 8.5 iirc.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and efficient algorithm is something like this:

```
foreach {a b c} $data {
   lappend ra $a
   lappend rb $b
   lappend rc $c
}
list $ra $rb $rc
```

The downside is here that you have to specify different variables.
Upside is that it is efficient.

Comment: And how do you modify this simple algorithm so that it answers the question? ;-) It's easy to write for a hardcoded `n`. See schlenk's answer for this wrapped into dynamic code generation. Your code also has a syntax error: `foreach` takes three arguments.